# how to dump postgres database in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-container

I have an application running in a docker container and psql database running in a docker container as well. i want to dump database while in django container, i know there is `dumpdata` in django but this command takes long time, i also tried `docker exec pg_dump` but inside django container this command doesn't work.

```
   services:
  db_postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata_invivo:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env

  django:
    build: .

    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
      - ./media:/media
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db_postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Is there any way to do `pg_dump` without using `docker exec pg_dump` while in django container?

Comment: Why not run `pg_dump` in the postgres container? `docker compose exec db_postgres pg_dump  <schema> > dump_file`

Comment: yes, but i need to do it in django app

Comment: @dev-beginer Well, you can install `postgresql-client` in your django app container. However, any particular reason to do that from app container?

Comment: i want to dump database in django admin for that i need to run pg_dump in django container

Answer (score 0):

While your container is running type:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

This will remove the volumes and thus all the data stored in your database of the container will be removed.

Now run

```
docker-compose up --build
docker-compose exec django python manage.py migrate
```

to create your tables again.